# prove by induction expression

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, summation, induction

Show that for all natural numbers $n$, the following equality holds:

> $$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{2i(2i-1)} = \sum_{i=n+1}^{2n}\frac{1}{i}$$

Can't seem to wrap my head around it...

Comment: RHS should have $2i$ , not $i$.

Comment: "The without induction" proof just implicitly uses induction, @S.C.B.

Comment: It's false for $n=1$.

Comment: changed it. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By induction hypothesis
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}\frac{1}{2i(2i-1)}=
\frac{1}{(2n+1)(2n+2)}+\sum_{i=n+1}^{2n}\frac{1}{i}
$$
On the other hand
$$
\sum_{i=n+2}^{2n+2}\frac{1}{i}=
-\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{2n+1}+\frac{1}{2n+2}+\sum_{i=n+1}^{2n}\frac{1}{i}
$$
So you just have to prove that
$$
-\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{2n+1}+\frac{1}{2n+2}=\frac{1}{(2n+1)(2n+2)}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $\frac{1}{2i(2i-1)}=\frac{1}{2i-1}+\frac{1}{2i}-\frac{1}{i}$